# Unable to add exchange mail account to Outlook on Windows 10

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office-2013, windows-10

I recently installed Windows 10 Pro N x64. It is all-new installation. I installed Office 2013 as well.

The problem is, that there is no `mail` menu item in Control Panel. I tried to search it via Start Screen/run via `control mlcfg32.cpl` and `control mlcfg64.cpl` and hack via `Settings -> Accounts` but everything with no luck. Maybe anybody knows any other way to open this nice window (when Outlook is closed):

[image: Mail Setup Outlook]

Comment: Is it possible that you don't need that menu anymore?

Comment: Have you tried going into Outlook and configure your account ? Outlook should ask you to configure itself on the first time, if not you can always open account setup wizard from File > account settings

Comment: Adding Exchange Mail Account requires to close Outlook

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somebody answered my question on Server Fault, but the question was migrated here and answer gone...

So, here is the answer. In Windows 10 there are Settings and Control Panel. And it is not that obvious. After explicit navigation to Control Panel you can see Mail icon and all old school stuff:

[image: Windows 10 Settings]
[image: Windows 10 Control Panel]

Answer (score 2):

To config Outlook in Windows 10 use the old control panel in C:\WINDOWS\system32\control.exe

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.